# Find other mails of the same thread in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, archiving, threading

I really love the threaded view in Mozilla Thunderbird. Because of this, I store my sent mails in the inbox, so I can move a whole thread to an archive folder in one drag and drop.

Sometimes I get answers to a thread that is already archived, and don't remember in which folder I put the old messages. I would be great, if Thunderbird shows me in which folder the other messages of this thread are - or even offers to archive it there.

Is this possible? I did not find any solution for that.

Comment: Well, I'd just copy the Subject and use the search function... maybe I have a better idea tomorrow :D

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the message and select *Open Message in Conversation*, which should show messages in this thread.  The right-most column of this view might already be *Location*, but if not, right-click the columns and add it.

You will then be able to see the folder each message in the thread is currently filed-in.