# How to automatically move a message in thunderbird to the folder containing the rest of the thread

Tags: email, thunderbird

To keep my mails in thunderbird (currently v45.2) organized, I move them to various subfolders manually. Now, when a new mail for an already existing thread arrives, it would be nice if I don't have to remember in which subfolder the rest of this thread was but could just move it to the folder that contains the rest of the thread by clicking one button.

In [Find other mails of the same thread in Thunderbird](https://superuser.com/questions/913500/find-other-mails-of-the-same-thread-in-thunderbird?rq=1), it is explained how one can easily find out in which folder the rest of the thread is stored. However, one still has to move the message manually. Is there maybe a plugin that provides a button "Move to folder XY", where XY is automatically replaced by the folder that contains the rest (or most) of the messages of the same thread?